# ASP.NET EF 'Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.'

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, entity-framework

Hola amigos estoy tratando de hacer un insert a mi BD, pero obtengo este error:

> 'Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.'

Este es mi `Insert`:

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult InsertRole(string role,string id_userCreated)
    {

        using (DBEnt db = new DBEnt())
        {

            var rolx = new AspNetRoles()
            {
                Name = role ,

            };
            db.AspNetRoles.Add(rolx);
            //db..add(cat);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        var action = "Insert";
        var comments = "Contadores ingresada por el usuario : ";
        InsertInBitacora(id_userCreated, action, comments + id_userCreated);
        return RedirectToAction("AdminRoles");
    }
```

Entiendo que me manda un error porque no le estoy pasando el `ID`, que junto con `Name` son los únicas columnas de mi tabla, quiero saber como puedo auto generar el famoso `ID`, que a todo esto es un `nvarchar(128)`, tal como pasa como pasa cuando se inserta un `user` en la tabla `[AspNetUsers]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno terminé por hacer esto, si alguien tiene una mejor solución siéntase libre de contestar.

```
    private static Random random = new Random();
    public static string RandomString(int length)
    {
        const string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
        return new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, length)
          .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
    }
```

Comment: Y te funcionó?. Resolviste tu problema?.

Comment: pues si ya puedo hacer insert sin problemas